# How do content providers works?

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider

Well, as far as I kwnow a content provider is a database, and is used to pass data through apps.

But this data can be accessed only in the phone that it was saved? Or if I saved some data using the app with phone1, can I retrieve it using the app with phone 2?

If it can't do the second option, what could I use to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: "a content provider is a database" -- no. It is an API. That API supports some database-style operations (query, insert, update, delete) and some streaming-style operations. "But this data can be accessed only in the phone that it was saved?" -- a `ContentProvider` itself can only be used on the device that is running the `ContentProvider`. Clients of that `ContentProvider` can pass that data to servers, etc. as those clients see fit.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think I got it, so if I want to share data between phones I need a server?

Comment: There is almost always some server involved, unless the devices are nearby and you can use something like Bluetooth or WiFiDirect.

Answer (score 0):

Content provider is not a database. You can think this as a layer between your app and underlying data. The data can be in sqlite database, file or something else. Content provider is very useful to access and store your data to database or file. You need this when you use syncadapter or widgets in your app. Now to answer your question, content provider of your app can be accessed by a different app in your same phone provided you use correct permission. As I mentioned it's not a database, so answer of second question is not. I would recommend you to read about content provider on android developer site to get the basic concepts.

Comment: Well, actually my goal is to pass data between cellphones with the same app. I thought content providers could do it. So what should I use?

Answer (score 0):

A content provider component supplies data from one application to others on request. Such requests are handled by the methods of the ContentResolver class. A content provider can use different ways to store its data and the data can be stored in a database, in files, or even over a network.